# Qt 5.2.1 with ICU support: all applications exit with code 1

Tags: linux, qt, cross-platform, embedded-linux, icu

I have a problem running QT 5.2.1 applications on linux embedded (all of them, even the simplest "hello world" exits with code 1).

I cross compiled QT 5.2.1 for a linux embedded device (TI AM335x) using the toolchain supplied by TI (SDK 6.00.00). I also added ICU support (because I am planning to cross-compile QtWebkit too and ICU is a required dependency).

So, I previously built ICU (version 52) and then I cross-compiled QT using the following configuration:

```
./configure -prefix /opt/qt5 -opensource -confirm-license -platform linux-g++
-icu -I /opt/icu/include -L /opt/icu/lib -R /opt/icu/lib -no-cups -no-nis
-no-dbus -no-pch -no-accessibility -no-gtkstyle -no-xcb -eglfs -no-directfb
-qpa eglfs-xplatform linux-arm-gnueabihf-g++ -opengl es2 -nomake examples
-nomake tests -v
```

(previously built ICU libraries reside in /opt/icu/lib).

QT was then compiled using `make && make install`, as usual.

Then I configured my QT Creator IDE on development machine (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit) for compiling applications against the new QT version, just cross-compiled, using the same toolchain provided by TI (SDK 6.00.00).

Everything is fine: my console-based "hello, world" application is compiled and then I am able to deploy it to the device (setting all the requested environment variables required for letting QT find its own libraries).

**BUT here comes the problem**:

the application always exits with code 1 and produces no output.

If I `strace` my application, running `strace -o trace.log ./TestConsole` then it produces the output that you can find [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=dcb987547568de13&id=DCB987547568DE13!107&ithint=file,.log&authkey=!ANC7D8Zh7ZfGz4w).

In other words it seems that somebody is calling `exit_group(1)` just after having loaded `libicudata.so.52`.

But who is calling it? and why?

Please consider that if I cross-build QT without ICU support, then I can compile and run applications against it... So I think it is something ICU-related... Any ideas about that?

Comment: Being (I think) the problem strictly ICU-related, then I refactored the question and published it under a new title [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859444/cross-compiled-icu4c-does-not-work-all-applications-exit-with-code-1)

Comment: Then please delete this question.

Comment: @KubaOber: I think it is much more useful to leave the question here... because it was hard for me to determine that the problem was due to ICU... maybe someone else is trying to compile QT (the subject of this question) and has the same problem... he won't look for questions ICU-related but for questions QT-related and then could land to this page and find the reference to the right question (and hopefully) solution. Am I wrong?

Comment: A question is useless if it doesn't have an answer. Either reformat the question so that you can post an answer to it yourself (that's fully OK), or delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: the problem is ICU-related.

I noticed that even the execution of the tool /opt/icu/bin/icuinfo on the target platform exits with 1 at startup (you can find the full strace log [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DCB987547568DE13!108&authkey=!AEZgEeISWwoMjs8&ithint=file,.log)).

A new ICU-related question has been published [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859444/cross-compiled-icu4c-does-not-work-all-applications-exit-with-code-1), so I think that this question can be closed.