# Cross-compiled ICU4C does not work (all applications exit with code "1")

Tags: cross-compiling, icu

I am experiencing a problem with ICU4C version 52.

I cross compiled it for TI AM335x board using the toolchain provided by TI (SDK 6.00.00); my development machine is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit.

The problem is that when I deploy the library to my target platform and launch any tool (like `icuinfo` or even any application which rely on ICU, e.g. a QT application) then it exits with code 1 (and no output is produced). If I `strace` the command, I obtain the output you can find [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=dcb987547568de13&id=DCB987547568DE13!108&ithint=file,.log&authkey=!AEZgEeISWwoMjs8).

In other words, it seems that somebody is calling `exit_group(1)` after having loaded `libicudata.so.52`.

But why? How can I fix the problem?

---

Just for reference, here is how I cross-compiled ICU (maybe I've made some mistakes?):

1) first of all I compiled ICU for my development machine:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --prefix=/opt/icu
  --disable-samples --disable-tests --with-cross-build=/opt/icupc
```

followed by:

```
make && make install
```

2) then I cross-compiled ICU: I've set my environment variables `AR`, `CC`, `CFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS`, `LIBS`, `CPPFLAGS`, `CXX`, `CXXFLAGS`, `CPP` for pointing to my cross-compiling toolchain and then:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --prefix=/opt/icu
  --with-cross-build=/home/morix/devel/icupc/source
```

followed by:

```
make && make install
```

3) at the end I copied the content of `/opt/icu` to my target platform and I've tried to run `icuinfo`, with no luck (as previously described).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution or at least a workaround.

For a reason that I could not determine, ICU fails to load its data (embedded in `libicudata.so.52`) at startup (when cross-compiled for ARM using *Linaro GCC toolchain*).

Digging into ICU documentation I discovered that I could compile ICU to package data in different ways, and I decided to package them in standard files. The configuration of ICU cross-compilation is done this way:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --prefix=/opt/icu
  --disable-samples --disable-tests
  --with-cross-build=/home/morix/devel/icupc/source
  --with-data-packaging=files
```

At run-time I have then to set my environment variable `ICU_DATA` to point to the data folders (which in my case is `/opt/icu/share/icu/52.1`) and the magic is done: ICU runs fine (`icuinfo` tool terminates with `ICU Initialization returned: U_ZERO_ERROR` which indicates success).

Comment: you can also use `u_setDataDirectory()` "first thing" to set the data path. http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/putil_8h.html#ab03241e29fc619a4b3f7737e98aa08ef